# Generalizing the property of two parabolas tangent to a circle, each of which touches it at two points

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

About five years ago, I discovered a property of a parabola, a circle that touches it at two points, and two tangents to it that are parallel to the index of the parabola.
[image]
In the previous picture $AC⊥BD$

After some trying, I was able to prove this with analytical geometry

But my happiness was soon complete until I was able to generalize this property, as it was not required for two parallel lines to be parallel to the index of the parabola.

[image]

I was also able to prove this with analytical geometry

But after a while I noticed that I could consider two parallel lines to be a special case of a parabola when the distance between the focus and the guide approaches zero and they are located at infinity.
The property is actually valid for two parabolas
[image]

Then, after a while, I found that this property was already known and was present in Arseniy Akuban’s book
[image]

This was frustrating, as I had used the previous properties in many applications and theorems

But after a while I was able to generalize this feature more:

I discovered that these two perpendicular lines are nothing but the interior bisector and exterior bisector of the angle between the diagonals of the quadrilateral whose vertices are the four points of contact, as shown in the picture:
[image]

Reaching this stage took almost a year of coming up with one generalization after anotherTheorems have been used along the way in many engineering constructions

But I still do not know how to prove this last general case. It is really difficult. I would be grateful for any help in proving this, and I prefer engineering methods to analytical methods.

Is the latest circular known?

Comment: The mentioned book of Arseniy Akuban is hard to find, not having it a potential answerer has to figure out a proof for the known facts, then try to attack the new ones (without knowing what was already done and what can be indeed useful for a complete proof of the new properties). The history of discovering this geometric configuration is nice and interesting, but unfortunately not helpful for the geometric insight so far. Please give a statement and the arguments for the known results. (In particular, the reader can see how much geometry and how much analytics are needed.)

Comment: I will add the pages in Arabic, and later, God willing, I will translate them into EnglishIn fact, we can take advantage of the above-mentioned and proven properties in creating parabolas using a ruler and compass. @dan_fulea

Comment: God is good to us, but wants us to live and have time to create beautiful things, so please only give a rough summary of what is already known, and which are the methods of proof. (Geometric properties of parabolas, or analytic geometry, or projective geometry of conics, or pole and polar arguments, or combined ones...) I am trying to give a decent elementary proof, but from the scratch it is very hard... The problem should at any rate get more attention, +1!

Comment: @dan_fulea I agree with you. I just discovered that some people have written a book of solutions to this book : https://booko.info/9789548880480/555-Geometry-Problems-Solutions-Based-on-Geometry-in-Figures-by-A-V-Akopyan?region=fr . By the way, I have improved my program...

Comment: Thank you very much @Jean-Marie, I have been looking for such a book for a long time

Answer (score 2):

Still not an answer, but I would like to share a generic SAGE program (SAGE is a free Python-like online resource ; see below this program and the way to run it). Writing this program has in fact be beneficial because of the need to compute analytical results that could be useful for reaching the assigned goal.

[image]

*Fig. 1.*

The principle is based on the following remark : parabolas externaly tangent to the unit circle **having a vertical-axis** constitute a family $(F)$ with common cartesian equation :

$$y=kx^2+s(k) \ \ \ \text{with this shift :} \ \ \ s(k):=-k-\frac{1}{4k}$$

depending on a single parameter $k$.

We can assume WLOG that the circle is the unit circle. Let us choose two parabolas $P_1$ and $P'_2$ of family $(F)$ with resp. parameters $k_1$ and $k_2$. $P_1$, featured in red on the figure, will be kept as it is. The second parabola $P_2$, will be the image by a rotation with angle $a$ of $P'_2$ (transformation of the dotted-blue parabola into the solid-blue parabola).

A result among others that I have found is that the point of intersection is

$$\left(\frac{\cos(a)w(k_1)-w(k_2)}{\sin(a)}, w(k_1)\right) \ \text{with} \ w(k)=-\tfrac{1}{2k}$$

---

Here is how one can execute this program  :

- ask https://sagecell.sagemath.org/
- copy-paste the program in the edit window,
- modify some parameters like $k_2$ (stretching of the blue parabolas) and/or rotation angle $a$.
- execute the program by clicking on the "Evaluate" button.

  ```
  var('x')
  k1=2;k2=3/2;a=2*pi/3; # parameters for parabolas P1 and P2
  L=2.5; # min and max values are -L < x,y < +L
  c=cos(a);s=sin(a)
  def w(k) : # ordinate of ref. chord
     return(-1/(2*k))
  def v(k) : # parabolas' vertical shift
     return(-k-1/(4*k))
  def h(k) : # half-chord length
     return(sqrt(1-1/(4*k^2)))
  def p(k,x) :
     return(k*x^2+v(k))
  def R(x,y) : # direct rotation
     return([c*x-s*y,s*x+c*y])
  def S(x,y) : # inverse rotation
     return([c*x+s*y,-s*x+c*y])
  g=circle((0,0),1,color='green') # unit circle
  g+=plot(p(k1,x),(x,-L,L),color='red') #  parabola P1
  u=p(k2,x)
  g+=plot(u,(x,-2,2),linestyle='dotted') # parabola P2 before,...
  g+=parametric_plot(R(x,u),(x,-L,L)) #  then after, rotation.
  g+=line([[-h(k1),w(k1)],[h(k1),w(k1)]],color='red') # chords 
  g+=line([R(-h(k2),w(k2)),R(h(k2),w(k2))])
  # equation giving the abscissas x of points of intersection of P1 and P2 :
  h=S(x,p(k1,x));sol=solve(p(k2,h[0])==h[1],x)
  # ordered list of abscissas of these points :
  X=[sol[n].rhs().real().n(20) for n in range(len(sol))]
  X.sort()
  Y=list(map(lambda x: p(k1,x), X)); # list of ordinates
  # the 2 diagonals with endpoints
  D=[[X[0],Y[0]],[X[2],Y[2]]]
  g+=line(D,color='cyan');g+=point(D,color='green',size=50)
  D=[[X[1],Y[1]],[X[3],Y[3]]]
  g+=line(D,color='cyan');g+=point(D,color='green',size=50)
  # common intersection point
  g+=point([(c*w(k1)-w(k2))/s,w(k1)],color='blue',size=50)
  g.set_axes_range(-L,L,-L,L)
  show(g)
  ```

Comment: Thank you, Jean-Marie. I am sure that your method is useful for those who want to reach an analytical proof. As for creating everything geometrically with a ruler and compass, it is possible, and if anyone requests it, I can tell him how the elements can be created.

Comment: A particular result : the sum of the abscissas of the intersection  points (list X in the program) is given by the simple formula : $- \ \frac{2}{k_1 \tan(a)}$ which, oddly, is independent of $k_2$.

Answer (score 1):

As for the properties resulting from special cases and their proof, I have discussed them in Arabic. I will translate them partially later, if he wishes. I will put them in picture form now...
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Steps to construct the tangent circle to a parabola at two points given one of The middle of the two contact points:
[image]

But I could not prove the case of perpendicularity of the two parabolas mentioned in Arseniy Akopyan's book. There are a few other details that I did not include in the pictures, but that is most of the work.

As for constructing a parabola that is tangent to a circle at two points, keep in mind that the center of the circle is a distance from the middle of the two tangent points, a distance equal to the distance between the focus and the index in the parabola.
The center of the circle passing through the center of the circle tangent to a parabola at two points and passing through the two points of tangency will be the focus of the parabola.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot for sharing the computations, the Arabic text is nice and more than clarifying, i was able some many years ago to also read some words...

Comment: Is it an arabic translation of Arsenyi Akopian's book ? If yes, please, translate some significant parts in order we understand the "articulations" of the proof(s). In its present state, I am unable to guess what is proven.

Comment: These results are things I arrived at using the GeoGebra program before I even learned about Arseniy Akopyan's book!First, I proved the property of two parallel lines, a parabola, and a circle if the two parallel lines were parallel to the index of the parabola, then I proved it in the general case for any slope.Then I used the previous facts to create the two circles that are tangent to a straight line and at the same time touch the parabola at two points. Then I used the previous properties to create a circle kissing the vertex of the parabola. @JeanMarie

Comment: I realize that I was completely misunderstanding !